# Read output from GNU GCC Compiler

Tags: python, gcc, output, stdout

I'm actually making a program in Python to run my C and C++ codes

When i tried to read the stdout of gcc, they return me nothing, an empty string

```py
import subprocess

output = ''
cam = "g++ main.cpp -o output.exe -std=C++11"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cam,  cwd='C:/test/', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.wait()
for line in proc.stdout:
    output += line.rstrip()
```

[And this is the real output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXrmm.png) (The error is proposital, just to check the output)

I just want to know how i read the output of GCC and copy to some variable

Comment: Just read `stderr` instead. or both

Comment: Please don't create images of text, copy-paste text *as text* into your questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `g++` outputs errors on STDERR, not STDOUT. You should use `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` if you wish to read those errors, which will then be available in `proc.stderr`.

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen(cam,  cwd='C:/test/', stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.wait()
for line in proc.stderr:
    output += line.rstrip()
```

Also notice that you should not use `.wait()` in this situation. You want to use `.communicate()` instead, as stated by [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait):

> **Note:** This will deadlock when using `stdout=PIPE` or `stderr=PIPE` and the child process generates enough output to a pipe such that it blocks waiting for the OS pipe buffer to accept more data. Use `Popen.communicate()` when using pipes to avoid that.